# Syncing data without an External Key?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, cad, data-management

I'm working with ArcGIS for desktop. I have received data from a third party and am trying to update my CAD system via GISLink. In order to connect the new data with the currently-used data, certain fields are required, the most important of which being a unique External Key field. In the new data tables, this field contains NULL values or is left out completely. In fact, there are no unique identifiers that match up between tables. I have so far been unable to reach the person who provided the data.

I am new to using GISLink and data management in general. Is there a way of working around this short of manually matching and calculating the leftovers? There are tens of thousands of rows, so this is not really a viable option.

It seems to me there is nothing I can do until I can contact the source, but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: Hello @Olive, correct me if I am wrong, you want to "join/connect/add" the new GIS data with existing CAD data based on a unique field?

Comment: That is correct. My problem is the existing CAD data doesn't share a field of unique values with which I can connect the new GIS data.

Comment: Do your datasets both have a location field? If so, you could do a spatial join.